# CSS Background no working on IE6

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have toggle tabs that when on click the background changes when active(I am using sprite). The problem is that the background doesn't change immediately, I still need to hover it to apply the changes. I think that using background or background-image is the problem because when I try using background-color, it works fine. This problem only occurs on IE6.

```
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    });



#menu-tabs ul li a {
    color: #000;
   background-image: url(../images/sprite.png) 0 20px no-repeat;
}

#menu-tabs ul li a.selected {
    color: #05416B;
    background-image: url(../images/sprite.png) 0 0 px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The solution is redirect IE6 users to Google Chrome Download page.

Comment: IE6? It probably doesn't change immediately because it has to find a computer still using it!

Comment: Have you tried the .toggleclass instead of .removeclass?

Comment: While I agree with the comments about ie6 being dead, the attitude that "there isn't someone out there with it and thus not supporting it" is very dangerous. Try simple pure CSS changes as a fall back.

Comment: @jobokai but how long we've to support IE 6? Even microsoft don't care now for IE6 and win XP. So why we should support and it up to us to encourage customer not to stick with older browser.

Comment: @KheemaPandey it's not a matter of strictly writing our code for IE 6 to support it, but writing our code so that no matter how you access it, regardless of antique browser, that our designs are at the very least functional. Having a disregard for the user and just telling them to redirect to download is not the correct approach. It's like you go to a restaurant and the server comes over and slaps you across the face because you are wearing and old coat, not a new one that is clean and shiny.

Comment: @Jobokai might be you right. I also faced this kind of challenge in past and to support the IE6 and IE7. But I educated my clents and customer and give them enough proof to convince them to not stick with these old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You have [syntax errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) in your rules; try correcting those first.

```
#menu-tabs ul li a {
    color: #000;
   background: url(../images/sprite.png) 0 20px no-repeat;
}

#menu-tabs ul li a.selected {
    color: #05416B;
    background: url(../images/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

`background-image` only supports image URL(s) (depending on browser; not all support multiple images). I suspect that, if your rules work on other browsers, then those browsers are simply normalizing your rules to the shorthand shown.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 6 has LOTS and LOTS of CSS bugs! 
Now, coming to your question,
Why background color works and why background image doesn't work. Color is something that the browser has in itself implicitly but it has to explicitly "load" images or other stuff.
Well, with IE6, its a total guess work here. I will recommend you to visit this site, http://positioniseverything.net/ 
They have a very comprehensive list of IE6 bugs. 
You may also visit the official Microsoft website on CSS compatibility.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

If you are still having problems, post a link to your actual page. 
Hope this helps.